# How to execute program without pthreadGC2.dll?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, static-libraries, mingw32

I use [Pthread Win32](http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) for programming in C.

If I use this command to compile my program with GCC/Mingw32:

```
mingw32-gcc.exe -c "Console.c" -o "Console.o"
mingw32-gcc.exe -o "Console.exe" "Console.o" "libpthreadGC2.a"
```

I need to put `pthreadGC2.dll` is the same directory or in the system folder.

#### How to combine my program with DLL(s)? Linker?

[image] (From Wikipedia)

Here are all the files might be needed:

1. libpthreadGC2.a ⇒ Statically-linked Library
2. pthreadGC2.dll ⇒ Dynamic-link Library
3. console.c ⇒ my c file

#### How to write the command? How to combine them together?

Comment: I have the same question and it is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28583154/3706301

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, we use -lpthread to link to pthread.so, the dynamic pthread lib.
in Windows, I think it's almost the same, like "-L /your/path/to/pthreadGC2.dll -lpthreadGC2".
Try some commands like this